# NodeJs + Postgres synchronus connection to Database to populate variable

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm using nodeJs express 3 framework with postgreSQL, I'm using the script below to look for a username in DB and populate a variable so I can pass it to my view.
Here is my script :

```
app.js
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
......
function fncCheckUsernameAvailability(vstrUsername){
    var pg = require("pg");
    var client = new pg.Client({user: 'xxx', password: 'xxxx', database: 'xxx', host: 'example.com'});
    var response = "";
    client.connect(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
  }
 client.query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='"+vstrUsername+"'", function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
        if(result.rows[0] == undefined){
            //console.log("Username available");
            response = "Username available";//Populating The variable here
        }else{
            //console.log("Username already taken");
            response = "Username already taken";//Populating The variable here
        }
    client.end();
  });
    });
    return response;
}


app.post("/Signup", function(req, res){
var username = req.body.username;
var Response = fncCheckUsernameAvailability(username);
console.log(Response);
}
```

The response variable is allways "undefined", so how can I make that script waiting until the DB checking is done to populate the "response" variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot place return values into asynchronous functions. You would instead need to use a callback, and this is what your code might look like:

```
function fncCheckUsernameAvailability(vstrUsername, callback) {
  client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
      return;
    }

    client.query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='" + vstrUsername + "'", function (err, result) {
      client.end();
      if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
        return;
      }

      if (result.rows[0] == undefined) callback(null, 'Username available.');
      else callback(null, 'Username taken.');
    });
  });
};
```

You would use the function like this:

```
app.post("/Signup", function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  fncCheckUsernameAvailability(username, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `err` contain? Put a `console.log(err)` before the `console.log(result)` and post what it contains.

Comment: Hi, really sorry I made a mistake in my table's name , now it is working perfect, thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is working `fncCheckUsernameAvailability(username, function(err, result) {console.log(result);});` it prints on console but this `fncCheckUsernameAvailability(username, function(err, result) {myVar = result;});` will not populate my variable is it something asynchrounous too?

Comment: It will populate the variable as long as it is within the callback. If it is null then you probably have an error somewhere.